# Shiny wellpanel width

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    wellPanel(tags$div(id="pane",
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6,valueBox("test","test1"),
             valueBox("test","test2"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 6,valueBox("test","test3"),
             valueBox("test","test4")

             ))), 
    tags$style(type="text/css","#pane{font-size:20px;}"))

    ))
# )




server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Results

[image]

However, I only need the highlighted portion; ie wellpanel width should be as per boxes

[image]

This is just an example, I will be adding four more boxes besides with a different wellpanel.

Answer (score 2):

Try using width in valueBox

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(column(width = 6, wellPanel(tags$div(id="pane",
         fluidRow(valueBox(width = 6, "test","test1"), valueBox(width = 6, "test","test2")),  
         fluidRow(valueBox(width = 6, "test","test3"), valueBox(width = 6, "test","test4")), 
         tags$style(type="text/css","#pane{font-size:20px;}")
    ))))
  )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {} 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what was causing the problem. Did Shiny assume that that valuebox where big enough?

Comment: The grid in the page layout has size 12, and the default size of the valueBox is 3. You also had the valueboxes in a column of size 6.

Comment: The grid in the page layout has size 12, and the default size of the valueBox is 4. You also had the valueboxes in a column of size 6. So the total space in  2 columns is (6)(6), and inside then you have  (4+4+4)(4+4+4), but you used only the first two slots (x+x+=)(=+=+=) .